# How to convert a dataframe with string in columns into csr_matrix

Tags: python, csr

I working on a PMI problem, so far I have a dataframe like this:

```
w = ['by', 'step', 'by', 'the', 'is', 'step', 'is', 'by', 'is']
c = ['step', 'what', 'is', 'what', 'the', 'the', 'step', 'the', 'what']
ppmi = [1, 3, 12, 3, 123, 1, 321, 1, 23]
df = pd.DataFrame({'w':w, 'c':c, 'ppmi': ppmi})
```

I want to convert this dataframe into a sparse matrix. Since `w` and `c` are lists of strings, if I do `csr_matrix((ppmi, (w, c)))`, it will give me an error `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`. What is another way to convert this dataframe?

Comment: I don't think `scipy` `csr_matrix` supports mixed-types, so I'm not sure what you are expecting... You might consider a `pandas` [sparse data structure](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/sparse.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try with `coo_matrix`:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sps
w = ['by', 'step', 'by', 'the', 'is', 'step', 'is', 'by', 'is']
c = ['step', 'what', 'is', 'what', 'the', 'the', 'step', 'the', 'what']
ppmi = [1, 3, 12, 3, 123, 1, 321, 1, 23]
df = pd.DataFrame({'w':w, 'c':c, 'ppmi': ppmi})
df.set_index(['w', 'c'], inplace=True)
mat = sps.coo_matrix((df['ppmi'],(df.index.labels[0], df.index.labels[1])))
print(mat.todense())
```

output:

```
[[ 12   1   1   0]
 [  0 321 123  23]
 [  0   0   1   3]
 [  0   0   0   3]]
```

Comment: This results in an error `AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'labels'`